# line endings in files which are checked out by svn and commited by git-svn

Tags: svn, git-svn

The team is using subversion as a version control system. I love git. So I cloned it with git-svn.

autocrlf setting:

```
$ git config core.autocrlf
true
```

So files changed by me will have LF as line ending.

When the files are checked out by other members with SVN, they will have LF as line-ending even on Windows.

Setting autocrlf to false can solve the problem. It tells git not to change CRLF to LF.

Can the problem be solved by configuring subversion client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both subversion and git have CRLF conversion setting. They can be set to anything, but they should be set consistently. Since in this case you want to use non-standard tools on the project, you are responsible to make sure you don't cause problems to the other team members. It seems the setting is not enabled in Subversion (it is set as property, thus recorded in repository there) so **turn `core.autocrlf` off now** and convert all files you screwed up back to the format they are supposed to be in!

Personally I'd never even consider turning autocrlf on. I am in similar situation and my experience is that there are files that must be in specific format on all systems, e.g. shell scripts (cygwin expects *unix* format) and MSBuild projects (must be windows format) and files that may be left in any format, like C++, Java, python, perl and about any other sources. So it's actually quite a bit of trouble to set CRLF conversion  to do what you need as you need to tell it about all the exceptions and there is absolutely nothing it would help (provided you don't try to edit in plain Notepad; most other editors including Notepad++, PSPad, Visual Studio, ViM etc. understand any format)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have turned it off before asking the question. And I will keep it false in the project.

Answer (score 1):

If svn eol property is set to 'native', the files are always checked out with EOL appropriate for the platform. So for example, checkout on Windows will have CR-LF, irrespective of the actual line endings saved to repository. We have been using this for cross-platform development for several years now.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the how to use svn in cross-platform projects. In my case, I will set autocrlf to false for it is a windows project.